# Spring Boot @Scheduled method can not access database relation

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

Jpa repositoy methods called from inside of a @Scheduled method is throwing PSQLException and saying the relation does not exist, where the same repository method is being executed fine without any problems from other parts of the code.

This is my @Configuration class for Scheduler,

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingConfig {

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        executor.setThreadFactory(new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("Scheduled-%d").build());

        ConcurrentTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ConcurrentTaskScheduler(executor);
        taskScheduler.setTaskDecorator(new MasterTaskDecorator());
        return taskScheduler;
    }

}
```

And this is the @Scheduled annotated method,

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000, initialDelay = 60000)
public void scheduledRevalidationOfOpenJourney() {
    List<JourneyEntity> openJourneys = journeyRepository.findAllByState(JourneyState.OPEN);
    openJourneys.forEach(openJourney -> openJourney.getDatasets().forEach(validationService::removeRelatedViolation));
}
```

From there on, this is the exception being thrown,

`2022-12-02 15:22:58.894 ERROR 32704 --- [   scheduling-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "journey" does not exist`

`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

`2022-12-02 15:23:58.896 ERROR 32704 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task`

`Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "journey" does not exist`

As I mentioned before, the table 'journey' does already exist and its repository methods are already being executed without any problems elsewhere in the code. Can anybody please point out what is causing this scenario and what could be the solution to it?

Comment: How did you initialize journeyRepository?

Comment: with constructor initialization in the @Service class.